# High correlation but low significance of p value

Tags: correlation

I'm just wondering why my results get correlation but there is no significance in p value? What if there is a correlation but there is no significant in p value of .05 and .01?

correlation: 1
N: 376

Comment: Tell us the sample size and the correlation...

Comment: correlation: 1, N: 376

Comment: If the correlation is identically 1 for such as sample size, then that is too good to be true  but it's significant at any conventional level. Draw a scatter plot to check.

Comment: Maybe you misinterpret the output of your software? E.g. it happens that people read '6.3402e-07' as '>0.05'. Or, since having exactly '1' is quite unrealistic for real life data sets, do you look at the correct place for the correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Your original Question doesn't specify the population correlation $\rho,$
the sample size $n$ or the sample correlation $r$ of interest.
But some experimentation that may answer your question is possible.

Suppose $X$ and $Z$ are independently distributed as $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and $-1 <\rho <1.$
Let $Y = X\rho + Z\sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$ Then $\mathrm{Cor}(X,Y) = \rho.$

Using simulation based on these relationships, one can specify $\rho$ and $n$ and then try to find a sample of size $n$ that
has $r$ not significantly different from $0.$ One successful
experiment with $\rho = 0.2$ and $n = 15$ is shown below
(P-value 0.0529).

```
rho=.2; n=15
x=rnorm(n); z=rnorm(n)
y=x*rho + z*sqrt(1-rho^2)
r = cor(x,y); r
[1] 0.5085183
cor.test(x,y)$p.val
[1] 0.05291103
summary(x)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-1.18008 -0.64317 -0.28560  0.03513  0.41765  2.43537 
summary(y)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-1.361635 -0.397631  0.205792  0.007405  0.342748  1.133783 
plot(x,y, pch=19)
```

[image]

However, the next run of this code may produce an $r$ that *is*
significantly different from $0.$

One can do 100,000 runs of the code and find that 89,024
out of the 100,000 fifteen-pair datasets do give values of $r$ that
are not significantly different from 0. The largest of them is about 0.514.

```
set.seed(2020)
rho=.2; n=15; m=10^5; pv = r = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
 x=rnorm(n); z=rnorm(n); y=x*rho + z*sqrt(1-rho^2)
 r[i] = cor(x,y); pv[i] = cor.test(x,y)$p.val  }
mean(pv > .05)
[1] 0.89024
mean(r[pv > .05])
[1] 0.1470825
min(r[pv > .05])
[1] 0.5139534
hist(r, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

Here is a histogram of the 100,000 sample correlations obtained
by the program. The non-significant ones are to the left of
the vertical red line.

[image]

A program with a much larger $\rho$ will generate occasional
samples with non-significant sample correlations. For example, out of 100,000 samples from a population with $\rho=0.8,$ I got 2605
non-significant $r$s.

So you can get many samples of size 15 with non-significant values of $r$ by choosing a relatively small $\rho$. Or you can get a
few by choosing a relatively large $\rho.$

You can get a disappointing non-significant sample correlation $r$
either because the population correlation $\rho$ is positive,
but small. Or because the population correlation is large, and
you're unlucky.